# Hello World on Visual Studio 2010 with Intel ArBB?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intel

I'm trying to get started working with Intel's Array Building Blocks, and there seems to only be one tutorial on "Hello World", at http://www.hpc.lsu.edu/training/tutorials/sc10/tutorials/SC10Tutorials/docs/M07/M07.pdf . And I'm not really getting it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and this is the code I got from the above link, kinda.

```
#include <C:/Program Files/intel/arbb/Beta6/include/arbb.hpp> 
//What do I have to do to make just "#include <arbb.hpp>" work?

using namespace arbb;

void my_function(f32& result, f32 input){
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    result = input + 1.0f; //"Error: no operator "+" matches these operands
}

int main(){
    typedef closure<void (f32&, f32)> mfc;
    mfc a = capture(my_function);
    mfc b = call(my_function);
    mfc c = call(my_function);
}
```

What else do I need to do to get "Hello World" working?

Comment: That's pretty vague.  Definitely Project + Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many samples available in arbb installation path. You can use the visual studio solution files to start with any of the sample. That is the easiest way.

In order to compile and run your own application from scratch, you have to have the include and dependencies set.

On Linux, you can add the path ~/(whatever)/intel/arbb/Beta6/include in the compile option using -I

On Windows, you can do:
set INCLUDE=C:/Program Files/intel/arbb/Beta6/include/arbb.hpp;

Or have a batch script that will ensure all the environment variables are set by default.

--- contents of the batch file ---

SET ARBB_OPT_LEVEL=O3
SET PATH=%ARBB_ROOT%\bin\ia32;%ARBB_ROOT%\bin\ia32\vs%MSVS_VERSION%;%OPENCV_ROOT%\bin;%FFTW_ROOT%;%FREEGLUT_ROOT%;%PTHREADS_ROOT%\lib;%PATH%

---- here is hello world program in arbb ---

```
#include <arbb.hpp>

void arbb_hello_map(arbb::i32& val)
{
  val = val * 2;
}
void arbb_hello(arbb::dense<arbb::i32>& data) 
{
  using namespace arbb;
  map(arbb_hello_map)(data);
}

int main() 
{
  using namespace arbb;
  int size = 5;
  dense<i32> data = dense<i32>(size);
  range<i32> write_data = data.write_only_range();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    write_data[i] = i;

  arbb::call(arbb_hello)(data);
  std::cout << "hello: " << std::endl;
  const_range<i32> read_data = data.read_only_range();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    std::cout <<"data["<<i<<"] = " << read_data[i] <<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

And compile it using

```
g++ -m64  -I/home/YOUR_NAME/arbb/install//include -Wall -Werror -O3 -W -Wshadow temp.cpp -o temp -L/home/YOUR_NAME/arbb/install/lib/intel64 -larbb_dev -ltbb -littnotify
```

Run it using
./temp